# MSVC pointer type attributes

Tags: c++, pointers, visual-c++

I recently ran into a compilation warning (promoted to error) using the 64-bit VS2013 compiler (update 3) making me aware of the existence of pointer type attributes.
The warning indicated a loss of precision as I was about to assign something of type 'Object *' to 'Object * __ptr32'.

I didn't hear about this '__ptr32' suffix yet, so I did some googling and found the following link: http://blog.aaronballman.com/2013/05/msvc-pointer-type-attributes/ .
After reading this, it became clear that I shouldn't simply ignore this warning as I might get ugly bugs in my 64-bit application...

Trying to pinpoint the problem further, I wrote following small program:

```
#include <type_traits>

struct O { };
struct OD { using V = O *; };

template <typename X, typename Y> struct expect_equal { static_assert(std::is_same<X, Y>::value, "Types do not correspond."); };

template <class D> using VD = typename D::V;
template <class D> struct Exp { template <template <class> class T> using DT = T<D>; };

int main(void)
{
   expect_equal<Exp<OD>::DT<VD>, O *> e;
   return 0;
}
```

While it would compile using clang, I got the following error/assertion failure using my MSVC 64-bit compiler (note: the 32-bit compiler did not yield compilation errors):

```
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 18.00.30723 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

test.cpp
test.cpp(6) : error C2338: Types do not correspond.
test.cpp(13) : see reference to class template instantiation 'expect_equal<O * __ptr32,O *>' being compiled
```

I was wondering whether someone could indicate what I am doing wrong here: I don't use an explicit pointer type attribute anywhere. This also might be a an unspecified behavior or a bug of either the STL implementation or the compiler, but most likely I am missing some important point here...  Thanks in advance!

Comment: AFAIK you and Charles Petzold are the only ones using that indentation style (of the original example)…

Comment: It looks like you were mixing modules compiled for 32 and 64 bits. Could you have a broken installation where the 64 bit compiler would still try to use a 32 bits library ?

Comment: I've reproduced the problem with 64-bit native compiler Visual C++ 2015. @SergeBallesta: No it's a compiler bug, related to handling of `using`.